# Как сделать чтобы генерировалось при каждой отправке

Tags: django, form, get

```py
def convert(str):
    num = decroman.decroman(str)
    result = num.result
    return result


def ajax_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    result = convert(request.GET["InputConvert"])
    return JsonResponse(data=dict(result=result))
```

У меня есть такой код, который генерирует ответ на полученных данных из формы. Ну к сожалению это работает только один раз из-за того что **viwes.py** генерируется только один раз при запуске. Как можно сделать чтобы можно было отправлять форму много раз?

**HTML**

```html
<div class="result_div">
    <p></p>
</div>

<form action="/result/" method="get" class="form_class">
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-5">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="InputConvert">Enter numbers</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" id="InputConvert" rows="10" required name="InputConvert"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Converting</button>
    </div>
</form>
<div class="form-group col-md-5">
    <label for="OutputConvert">Convert</label>
    <textarea class="formresult" readonly id="StaticResult" rows="10" class="form-control"></textarea>
</div>
```

**layouts.html**

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('form.form_class').submit(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropogation();

                var form_data = $(this).serialize();
                $.ajax({
                    url: $(this).attr('action'),
                    method: $(this).attr('method'),
                    data: form_data,
                    success: function (data) { $('.result_div').html(data.result); }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

https://github.com/illiashvedov/DecRoman

Comment: не хватает кода шаблона и если есть - js. добавьте в вопрос

Comment: @ZaArs Добавил код шаблона

Comment: 1 вариант - выводить результат на тойже странице, 2 - ajax

Comment: А как вот именно сделать первый??

Comment: если будут вопросы, пишите сюда - поговорим в чате

Comment: @ZaArs Есть вопросы

Comment: @ZaArs Я к сожалению ещё не могу в чатах общаться((

Comment: Странно. Тогда обновите код в вопросе, добавьте JS если используете

Comment: Добавил и так же оставил ссылку на репозиторий

Comment: Обновил репозиторий, читайте

Comment: Извиняюсь, вижу изменения в ответе, но не вижу изменений в репозитории

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1-й вариант - форма вместе с результатом

```
# forms.py

class DecRomanForm(forms.Form):
    field1 = forms.<Field...> ...
    ....

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        # Проверяем если надо
        # Cчитаем
        cleaned_data['result'] = result
        return cleaned_data
```

```
# views.py

def view_name(....):
    ...
    context['form'] = DecRomanForm(request.GET)
    ...
```

```
{# html template #}

{% if form.is_valid %}
   {# Вывод результат #}
   {{ form.cleaned_data.result }}
{% endif %}

<form ... >
   {{ form }}
</form>
```

2 - через Ajax.

```
# ajax view

def ajax_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    # считаем результат на основе данных
    return JsonResponse(data=dict(result=result))
```

```
# jQuery (js)

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('form.<form_class>').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    e.stopPropagation();

    var form_data = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
      url: $(this).attr('action'),
      method: $(this).attr('method'),
      data: form_data,
      success: function(data) { $('.result_div').html(data.result); }
    });
  });
});
```

```
{# HTML template #}

<script src="{% static "path/to/js/script.js" %}"></script>
<div class="result_div"></div>

{# А тут форма выводится #}
<form class="<form_class>"> ... </form>
```

---

UPDATE: У вас не работало из-за
1. Отсутствия jQuery
2. Моей опечатки в stopPropagation
3. В методе DecRoman у вас coding (который zip) ставится по умолчанию в параметре метода. Для таких объектов, он сосздается один раз. После обработки zip очищался. Решается переносом в локальную переменную, которую можно переопределить через параметр. Или вообще убрать параметр.

---

UPDATE: diff

```
Index: src/convector/decroman.py
IDEA additional info:
Subsystem: com.intellij.openapi.diff.impl.patch.CharsetEP
<+>UTF-8
===================================================================
--- src/convector/decroman.py   (revision 58d1a78dd0a91fbda459f51b3c010b852d581fed)
+++ src/convector/decroman.py   (revision e064f9f2162685211d36752e551f6c66cb66f0d6)
@@ -38,10 +38,12 @@
         elif self.validRoman():
             return False

-    def DecToRoman(self, coding=zip(
-        [1000, 900, 500, 400, 100, 90, 50, 40, 10, 9, 5, 4, 1],
-        ["M", "CM", "D", "CD", "C", "XC", "L", "XL", "X", "IX", "V", "IV", "I"]
-    )):
+    def DecToRoman(self, coding=None):
+        if coding is None:
+            coding = zip(
+                [1000, 900, 500, 400, 100, 90, 50, 40, 10, 9, 5, 4, 1],
+                ["M", "CM", "D", "CD", "C", "XC", "L", "XL", "X", "IX", "V", "IV", "I"]
+            )
         result = []
         for d, r in coding:
             while self.dec >= d:
Index: src/convector/templates/convector/convector.html
IDEA additional info:
Subsystem: com.intellij.openapi.diff.impl.patch.CharsetEP
<+>UTF-8
===================================================================
--- src/convector/templates/convector/convector.html    (revision 58d1a78dd0a91fbda459f51b3c010b852d581fed)
+++ src/convector/templates/convector/convector.html    (revision e064f9f2162685211d36752e551f6c66cb66f0d6)
@@ -1,5 +1,25 @@
 {% extends "convector/layouts.html" %}

+{% block extra_head %}
+    <script type="text/javascript">
+        $(document).ready(function () {
+          var form = $('form.form_class');
+          $('form.form_class').find('button[type="submit"]').click(function (e) {
+                e.preventDefault();
+                e.stopPropagation();
+
+                var form_data = form.serialize();
+                $.ajax({
+                    url: form.attr('action'),
+                    method: form.attr('method'),
+                    data: form_data,
+                    success: function (data) { $('.result_div').html(data.result); }
+                });
+            });
+        });
+    </script>
+{% endblock extra_head %}
+
 {% block main_section %}
 <div class="result_div">
     <p></p>
Index: src/convector/templates/convector/layouts.html
IDEA additional info:
Subsystem: com.intellij.openapi.diff.impl.patch.CharsetEP
<+>UTF-8
===================================================================
--- src/convector/templates/convector/layouts.html  (revision 58d1a78dd0a91fbda459f51b3c010b852d581fed)
+++ src/convector/templates/convector/layouts.html  (revision e064f9f2162685211d36752e551f6c66cb66f0d6)
@@ -14,22 +14,8 @@
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'convector/main.css' %}">

     <title>{{ title }}</title>
-    <script>
-        $(document).ready(function () {
-            $('form.form_class').submit(function (e) {
-                e.preventDefault();
-                e.stopPropogation();
-
-                var form_data = $(this).serialize();
-                $.ajax({
-                    url: $(this).attr('action'),
-                    method: $(this).attr('method'),
-                    data: form_data,
-                    success: function (data) { $('.result_div').html(data.result); }
-                });
-            });
-        });
-    </script>
+    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
+    {% block extra_head %}{% endblock %}
 </head>

 <body>
```

Comment: Первый вариант понравился, ну если вам не сложно оставьте и второй потому что я искал через ajax там не сильно много хороших примеров возможно кому-то пригодится

Comment: обновил ответ для вас

Comment: А вот в Аякс там данные получить с помощью ```request.GET['InputConvert']``` ?

Comment: Ну точнее похожим методом?

Comment: Да так и получать, все хранится в request.<METHOD>

Comment: у request вроде есть еще метод is_ajax() , но это не точно. Возможно он находится в generic views, давно не работал с ним

Comment: Я понял, благодарю тогда буду пробовать

Comment: Можете подсказать ответ не возвращается

Comment: добавил  diff в ответ

Comment: Благодарю вас!!!!!

Comment: Всё получилось всё работает